# Connect to Azure Virtual Machine with WinRM Enabled using Http

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, winrm

I can access my azure vm (windows) using http://terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/ and it can't access with https://terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/ (no SSL in machine). But I enabled the 443 port for https in this VM. I am seeing both http and https  WinRM listeners running in my VM i.e. http without a thumb nail and https with a thumb nail.

> My question is that can I connect to my WinRM enabled azure VM using
>   http? or is it a mandatory for https here?

Comment: Did you open the ports in the firewall as well as add network security group rules for all the ports?

Comment: I only added the rule in nsg for both http and https. I thought that's enough for azure vm. What additional to do with firewall? Is it need to do by login to VM or possible through azure portal? I am not fair with network deals :)

Comment: You need to RDP to the machine and open the firewall ports as needed. The default ports open are 80 and 3389 so you would need to add 443 to get it to work. Try adding it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I will open 443 in firewall for https and try. But 443 is for https and can I connect using http without opening this firewall port? something like...Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri  http://terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:5985 -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck) -Authentication Negotiate? See, I used 5985 WinRM port for http.

Comment: Tried "$cred = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri  https://terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:5986 -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationChec
k) -Authentication Negotiate" with an error

Comment: Connecting to remote server terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com failed with the following error message : The SSL connection cannot be established. Verify that the
service on the remote host is properly configured to listen for HTTPS requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS
or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig -transport:https". For more
information, see the about...

Comment: have you also added a NSG for 5985/ 5986?

Comment: In WinRM, I added 5985,5986 as destination port range for NSG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About enable Azure VM WinRM, you should add port 5985 to Azure VM's **NSG inbound rules** and add port 5985 to **windows firewall inbound rules**.

Then use this script to create a session:

```
$username = 'user'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

Here are my steps:

WinRM server:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> Enable-PSRemoting -force
PS C:\Users\jason> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
The following changes must be made:

Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.

Make these changes [y/n]? y

WinRM has been updated for remote management.

Configured LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.
```

Client:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts = "13.78.103.201"}'
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = 13.78.103.201

PS C:\Users\jason> $username = 'jason'
PS C:\Users\jason> $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string '122130869@qq' -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\Users\jason> $cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
PS C:\Users\jason> $s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://13.78.103.201:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)

PS C:\Users\jason> Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://13.78.103.201:5985' -Credential $cred
[13.78.103.201]: PS C:\Users\jason\Documents>
[13.78.103.201]: PS C:\Users\jason\Documents>
[13.78.103.201]: PS C:\Users\jason\Documents>
```

Note: Add port 5985 to NSG inbound rules and windows firewall settings.

Comment: Thx. Just tried above https way after NSG and Firewall verification for 5985. I got error as "terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are
currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.". Some possible reasons also mentioned, but no space here to paste those text...

Comment: @JaishMathews that just http, not https, are you want to use https to Winrm?

Comment: I am trying with http only and used above command you put, which is http itself. But got error as mentioned in my prev. comment.

Comment: Which authentication method are you use?  could you re-configure WinRM(remove all winrm listener) and try to use `winrm quickconfig` to enable it.

Comment: No manual config for authentication method,but used uid/pwd text. All deleted by "winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS"&"winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP" to run "winrm quickconfig". Now winrm has single listener as "Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.0.0.5, 127.0.0.1, ::1, 2001:0:9d38:6abd:30b2:2abd:f5ff:fffa, fe80::5efe:10.0.0.5%5, fe80::30b2:2abd:f5ff:fffa%6, fe80::bc09:a95:3b0c:8555%7" and same error too

Comment: @JaishMathews I have update my answer, please check it:)

Comment: Excellent!!! I tried with both IP and URL and worked. Issue was I never registered trusted host locally. It really helped and I used below trusted host registration for URL "winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts = "terraformrg.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com"}". One last question as once registered trusted hosts would be there for always even after powershell instance closed? Thanks for your time

Comment: Some additional to this. You need below commands to run in your WinRM machine so that tools like terraform can copy files from your local to your WInRM enabled machine. winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled false